# Unexpected result from PostgreSQL information schema

Tags: postgresql, schema, database-size, information-schema

I have written a simple query that should show all table sizes of any given schema in human-readable format:

```
select table_name, pg_relation_size(quote_ident(table_name))
from information_schema.tables
where table_schema = 'my_schema'
order by 2
```

When I run this query in PgAdmin, I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  relation "my_table" does not exist
SQL state: 42P01
```

How can this error even be possible?  I have not changed the information_schema at all and, if a relation doesn't exist in the first place, why would it be in the information_schema ?   Any idea how this could happen?

Comment: postgres has like all rdms a lot of bugs, report it

Comment: @nbk: while I agree that no software is free of bugs, I wouldn't qualify Postgres as having "lots of them". And this is probably not one to begin with, rather a user error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only reason I can think of, is if `my_schema` is not part of your `search_path`.

As you pass a table name without schema qualifying it to the function `pg_relation_size()` the table is searched in the default search_path. If it's not found, you'll get that error.

Use a fully qualified name instead:

```
pg_relation_size(format('%I.%I', table_schema, table_name))
```

Comment: i think it is an error as my_table exists in the table schema, but the error says that the table doesn't exist

Comment: @nbk: no it's not an error. `my_table` references a table in the default schema/search_path (e.g. `public`) . `my_schema.my_table` references the table in the specific schema.

Comment: I would phrase this even stronger because I think the default search_path is `<username>, public`, so unless OP fiddled with the search_path, we *know* that `my_schema` is not in the search_path.